# Continuous mapping and fixed points

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

Does a continuous mapping $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ which satisfies $f(f(x))=x$ for each $x \in \mathbb R$ necessarily have a fixed point?

Comment: (Yes) Have you tried something to prove it?

Comment: Ciao (your name looks like it's coming from my country). Anyway, in class (it's first year PhD math for economists) we covered cases where a function is non decreasing and then Tarski theorem makes sense. Browel tells me that if a function maps from a compact and convex space to another compact and convex space it has a fixed point. Should I go in that direction? I'm kinda lost. And I have 4 more exercises like that one. Please...a direction....Thanks a lot

Comment: What can you say about $f$ monotonicity?

Comment: @WillJagy $x \mapsto 1/x$ is not a continuous map $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Alright, second try: Q1: if we ***always*** have $f(x) > x,$ what does that say about $f(f(x))?$ Q2:if we ***always*** have $f(x) < x,$ what does that say about $f(f(x))?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f(a) = b$ for some $a \neq b$, then $f(b) = f(f(a)) = a$.
Define $g(x) = f(x) -x$, and we have 
$$g(a) = f(a) - a = b-a$$
and 
$$g(b) = f(b) - b = a-b$$
from $g$ is continuous, by intermediate value theorem, there exists $c$ between $a,b$ such that 
$$g(c) = f(c) - c = 0$$
because $b-a$ and $a-b$ have opposite signs.

Comment: Thanks. This looks elegant. Yes, brilliant

Answer (score 2):

Extended hints:

1. We can assume that $f(0)\neq0$. Without loss of generality we can then also assume that $f(0)>0$. This is because if $f(f(x))=x$ for all reals $x$, then also $F(F(x))=x$ for all $x$, where I define $F(x)=-f(-x)$. Furthermore, $f(-x)=-x$ iff $F(x)=x$, so if one has a fixed point so does the other. All this amounts to is that we can study $F$ instead of $f$ to get $f(0)>0$.
2. Look at the restriction of $f$ to the interval $[0,f(0)]$. Notice that $f$ maps the endpoints of this interval to each other. Plot the graphs of both $f$ and the identity function $id(x)=x$. Why must they intersect in this interval? Bolzano's theorem (or intermediate value theorem) on $g(x):=f(x)-x$.

Comment: The same idea as in Will Jagy's comment. Specified a bit.

Comment: If step 1. feels strange, you can skip it and split the treatment in step 2 into two cases. You study the restriction of $f$ to either $[0,f(0)]$ or $[f(0),0]$ depending on the sign of $f(0)$.

Comment: I think the OP ran away. Or  fell asleep